# For each row in a data.table, get the quantile of a value relative to matching rows from another table

Tags: r, data.table

A tough one to title - best explained with an example...

Here I split the iris table into train/test with 140 and 10 rows respectively:

```
set.seed(2017)
irisDT <- data.table(iris)
irisDT[, IrisId := .I]
train <- irisDT[sample(.N, 140)]
test <- irisDT[!train, on="IrisId"]

> train
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species IrisId
  1:          6.0         3.0          4.8         1.8  virginica    139
  2:          5.5         2.4          3.8         1.1 versicolor     81
  3:          5.6         2.5          3.9         1.1 versicolor     70
  4:          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa     43
  5:          6.8         3.0          5.5         2.1  virginica    113
 ---                                                                    
136:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9  virginica    147
137:          5.8         2.6          4.0         1.2 versicolor     93
138:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3     setosa     18
139:          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2  virginica    118
140:          6.5         3.0          5.5         1.8  virginica    117

> test
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species IrisId
 1:          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2     setosa     21
 2:          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2     setosa     37
 3:          5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3     setosa     41
 4:          6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor     57
 5:          6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor     59
 6:          6.1         2.8          4.0         1.3 versicolor     72
 7:          5.5         2.4          3.7         1.0 versicolor     82
 8:          6.7         3.1          4.7         1.5 versicolor     87
 9:          6.2         2.8          4.8         1.8  virginica    127
10:          6.9         3.1          5.4         2.1  virginica    140
```

Now, for each `test` sample, I want to get

1. The average Petal.Width from `train` for matching species
2. The quantile of the `test` Petal.Width based on Petal.Widths from `train` for matching species

### Ugly solution

```
ecdf_fun <- function(vals, x){
  # Returns the percentile of x in relation to vals

  ecdf(vals)(x)
}

vals <- train[test, on="Species", allow.cartesian=TRUE][, list(
  AvgPetal.Width = mean(Petal.Width), QuantilePetal.Width=ecdf_fun(Petal.Width, i.Petal.Width[1])
  ), keyby=i.IrisId]
test[vals, `:=`(AvgPetal.Width = i.AvgPetal.Width, QuantilePetal.Width = i.QuantilePetal.Width), on=c("IrisId"="i.IrisId")]

> test
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species IrisId AvgPetal.Width QuantilePetal.Width
 1:          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2     setosa     21         0.2468              0.6809
 2:          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2     setosa     37         0.2468              0.6809
 3:          5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3     setosa     41         0.2468              0.8085
 4:          6.3         3.3          4.7         1.6 versicolor     57         1.3244              0.9556
 5:          6.6         2.9          4.6         1.3 versicolor     59         1.3244              0.5556
 6:          6.1         2.8          4.0         1.3 versicolor     72         1.3244              0.5556
 7:          5.5         2.4          3.7         1.0 versicolor     82         1.3244              0.1333
 8:          6.7         3.1          4.7         1.5 versicolor     87         1.3244              0.9111
 9:          6.2         2.8          4.8         1.8  virginica    127         2.0292              0.3125
10:          6.9         3.1          5.4         2.1  virginica    140         2.0292              0.6458
```

Is there a better way using data.table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's...

```
setkey(train, Species, Petal.Width)

# get quantile
test[, q := {
  pw = Petal.Width
  train[.BY, on=names(.BY), findInterval(pw, Petal.Width)/.N]
}, by=Species]

# get mean
test[train[, mean(Petal.Width), by=Species], on=.(Species), m := i.V1 ]
```

Avoiding the Cartesian join gives some hope of scaling this up without running out of memory, I guess.

---

*How it works*

`.BY` is a list containing the columns in the `by=` argument. With it, if you change the code to use a different set of `by=` columns, the code doesn't need to be rewritten.

`X[Y, on=, j]` is the syntax for a join.

Comment: Thanks Frank.  Can you explain the `train[.BY, on=names(.BY)` part?

Comment: @Ben Sure, added some explanation. If you don't know about joins, there's documentation in `?data.table` and I have some notes here  http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#dt-joins